# Free Provisioning Profile via command-line without Apple Developer account

Tags: ios, xcode7

I want to create a free provisioning profile for iOS development via command-line (i.e. never touching the Xcode GUI, however, I can still use Xcode's command-line tools), without a developer account.

Is this possible? If so, how?